# How do I place my textview under another?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to place my `textview4` below, my `sourceNameTextView`, but i can't see the text from `textView4`? I am new to using relative layout can someone tell me why this is happening and how to fix this? I already tried reading some post on stackoverflow but can't find anything that fixes this issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:padding="6dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/newsThumbnail"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newsBody"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"


        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/sourceName"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/newsThumbnail"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sourceName"


        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/newsThumbnail"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textColor="#9A9CA5"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/newsThumbnail"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sourceName"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextViwew.." />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you don't see `textView4` because you added `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to  the `sourceName` `TextView`,

This means that that you want to align a view which is `textView4` to be beneath of a View that is exactly at the bottom of the parent.

So, the `textView4` will be off the screen or correctly speaking will be off the `RelativeLayout` (under the bottom of it)

To Solve this You need to remove `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` from the `sourceName` `TextView`

Also when you do this change you will notice that `newsBody` now is gone, that is because you added `android:layout_above="@id/sourceName"` to it and didn't constraint the `sourceName` to be at the bottom of it.

You can use now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:padding="6dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/newsThumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newsBody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/newsThumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/newsThumbnail"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sourceName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/newsBody"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/newsThumbnail"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textColor="#9A9CA5"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sourceName"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/newsThumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/newsThumbnail"
        android:text="TextViwew.." />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Also like Zain said, you had alignParentBottom which caused the view to push your layout out of the view. Try to avoid fixed height if you don't really have to use it. But either way, I think that using `LinearLayout` would make your life much easier and in the future it will be easier to edit the code.

You can't see the `TextView` because you set a fixed height on your `RelativeLayout`. Other layouts take too much space and because of that your `TextView` is below `sourceName` but not visible as it's out of the layout.

To change this you can add `wrap_content` as height for your `RelativeLayout`. Then you'll have to play a lot with layout attributes to get what you want. What you are trying to achieve is way easier if you just use `LinearLayout` for the right part of your layout. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:padding="6dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/newsThumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/newsThumbnail"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/newsBody"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:text="NEWS BODY"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sourceName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textColor="#9A9CA5"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextViwew.." />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The result for this:

[image]

Comment: Glad I could help. Also, Zain offered you the solution below without using the LinearLayout. It's just that your code was really messy so try to write clean code it will help you a lot in the future edits.